# PHP get position of each first character in a string into an array

Tags: php, regex, position

Given a string, for example:

```
$string = "  this     is   a   string  ";
```

What is the best approach to return an csv array containing one number for each word that represents its first characters position like this:

```
$string = "  this     is   a   string  ";
             ^        ^    ^   ^
             2        11   16  20
```

Ideally the output would just be an array:

```
2,11,16,20
```

So far, here is what I have but I think this is a bit over my head given my limited skills:

```
$string = "  this     is   a   string  ";
$string = rtrim($string); //just trim the right sides spaces
$len = strlen($string);
$is_prev_white = true;
$result = "";
for( $i = 0; $i <= $len; $i++ ) {
    $char = substr( $string,$i,1);
    if(!preg_match("/\s/", $char) AND $prev_white){
        $result .= $i.",";
        $prev_white = false;
    }else{
        $prev_white = true;
    }   
}
echo $result;
```

I am getting:
    2,4,11,16,20,22,24,26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, but *progressive* :) solution with `preg_match_all` and `array_walk` functions:
Use `preg_match_all` function with `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag:

> **PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE** : If this flag is passed, for every occurring match the appendant string offset will also be returned. Note that this changes the value of **matches** into an array where every element is an array consisting of the matched string at offset 0 and its string offset into **subject** at offset 1.

```
$string = "  this     is   a   string  ";   // subject
preg_match_all("/\b\w+\b/iu", $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

array_walk($matches[0], function(&$v){   // filter string offsets
    $v = $v[1];
});
var_dump($matches[0]);

// the output:
array (size=4)
  0 => int 2
  1 => int 11
  2 => int 16
  3 => int 20
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: This appears to be the right answer but I am unable to get them into the format `2,11,16,20` that I was trying to. What is the easiest way to arrive at a csv list as shown?

Comment: @TripleC, the easiest way to get those array with string offsets into csv string is to use the `implode` function : `var_dump(implode(",", $matches[0]));` gives `string '2,11,16,20'`

Comment: I had one other question. A few of my words have symbols inside of them like, for example, `ca#t` How can I fix this regex to include words with symbols in them?

Comment: @TripleC, to handle such words as `ca#t` change regexp pattern to this: `"/\b[a-zA-z#]+\b/iu`

Answer (score 1):

Php regex matching provides a flag to return te offsets instead of the matched substrings. Use the following snippet:

```
$hits = [];
preg_match_all("/(?<=\s)\w/", "  this     is   a   string  ", $hits, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$result = array_column ( $hits[0], 1 );
$s_result = join ( ", ", $result);
echo $s_result;
```

The regex pattern employs positive lookbehind to find the first char after a whitespace character. The call to `array_column` extract the result data from the multidimensional array returned as the pattern match description. `join` concatenates the array elements into a string, the chosen separator turns it into a csv line.

For more details, refer to the php docs for [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Live example [here](https://3v4l.org/OLlVG). According to this site, the solution works as of php 5.5.0.

Comment: Will this work in cases where the string begins with a word instead of a space?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Partially, it won't find the first occurrence. Unfortunately, the lookbehínd argument must be fixed length, sio the canonical alternation `(^|\s)` won't work. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

You want the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag:

```
$string = "   this     is   a   string  ";
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\s)([^\s])/', $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$result = $matches[1];

echo var_dump($result);
```

The regex is:

```
(?:^|\s) // Matches white space or the start of the string (non capturing group)
(^\s) // Matches anything *but* white space (capturing group)
```

Passing PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE makes preg_match() or preg_match_all() return matches as two-element arrays that contain both the matching string and that match's index inside the searched string. The result of the above code is:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "t" [1]=> int(2) } 
    [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "i" [1]=> int(11) } 
    [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> int(16) } 
    [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "s" [1]=> int(20) } 
}
```

So you could get the array of just the indexes with

```
$firstChars = array_column($result, 1);
```

Comment: Will this work in cases where the string begins with a word instead of a space?

Answer (score 0):

The pattern that you're looking for is simple enough that a regex isn't necessary to match it. You can do this by just looping over the string.

```
$l = strlen($string);
$result = array();

// use this flag to keep track of whether the previous character was NOT a space
$c = false;

for ($i=0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    // if the previous character was a space and the current one isn't...
    if (!$c && $string[$i] != ' ') {
        // add current index to result
        $result[] = $i;
    }
    // set the 'not a space' flag for the current character
    $c = $string[$i] != ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with two flags.

```
$string = "  this     is   a   string  ";

$flags = PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE;

// \W+ matches one or more non word characters
$csv = implode(",", array_column(preg_split('/\W+/', $string, -1, $flags), 1));
```

```
echo $csv;
```

> 2,11,16,20

If you need the words with offset, just remove the `array_column` and `implode` part.

```
$res = preg_split('/\W+/', $string, -1, $flags);
```

```
print_r($res);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => this
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => is
            [1] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => 16
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => string
            [1] => 20
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this without regex. I hope it's work for you.

```
$str="   w  this     is   a   string  ";
echo "<pre>";
print_r(first_letter_index($str));

function first_letter_index($str)
{
    $arr2 = array_map('trim',str_split($str));
    $result=array();
    foreach($arr2 as $k=>$v)
    {
        if(!empty($v) && empty($arr2[$k-1]))
        {
            $result[$k]=$v;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```